RunnableSequence instead of LLMChain throws an error (updating from depreacated langchain)
When I have this code first
from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import transformers
import torch

model="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

pipeline=transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    device_map="auto",
    max_length=1000,
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=10,
    num_return_sequences=1,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id
    )

llm=HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipeline, model_kwargs={'temperature':0})

from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
prompt_template=PromptTemplate(input_variables=["book_name"],
                               template="Provide me a concise summary of the book {book_name}")

and then I complete it with
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_template, verbose=True)
response= chain.run("Alchemist")
print(response)

I get a response with the summary I wanted , but I get deprecation warnings.
So following the warnings I try to replace the second part with
chain = prompt | llm
response = chain.invoke("The name of the rose")
print(response)

but I get the error
TypeError: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict.Instead got an unsupported type: <class 'str'>

What am I doing wrong?
I have used something similar but with llm being a HuggingFaceEndPoint and in that case it worked, so I suspect that it has to do with llm being a HuggingFacePipeline but can someone tell me how to correct the code?
Edit:
I tried
chain2 = prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()
response2 = chain2.invoke({"bookname":"The name of the rose"})
# response2 = chain2.invoke("The name of the rose")
print(response2)

but the error persists

i guess it's invoke({"bookname": "The name of the rose"})

From the official docs, there seem to be something missing at the end of your pipeline, that is some sort of OutputParser : https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chains/langchain.chains.llm.LLMChain.html.

@jeb the error occurs in the line before that

@Alphasaft LLChain works fine, but it is deprecated

@Alphasaft Also this works well with OpenAI or -as I mentioned- with HuggingFaceEndPoint, but not with HuggingFacePipeline

Yes, I know, but look just below it (the proposed not-deprecated replacement) : the chain is "prompt | llm | >> StrOutputParser() <<". When you go to the StrOutputParser docs, it says it implements Runnable. Considering your error message I think this is worth a try. Plus this would explain why a HuggingFaceEndPoint works fine, but not a HuggingFacePipeline : your, well, pipeline lacks an end point. Or is there something I'm not getting ?

@Alphasaft Thanks, I tried it but it did not work

Hm, ok, sorry then.

No prob. I think the problem is in HuggingFacePipeline

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The reason turns out to be quite silly.
The prompt was called actually prompt_template not prompt.
Also the suggestion to use dictionaries, threw an error
The correct code is
chain2 = llm | prompt_template
response2 = chain2.invoke("The name of the rose")
print(response2)


Shouldnt the first line be: chain2 = prompt_template | llm ?

Try this:
chain = prompt | llm
chain.invoke(input={"bookname": "The name of the rose"})


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
